# How to get the duplicate key values in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

my input is :

```
someMap = { "item": "first" , "item": "second" }
```

template:

```
<#list someMap?keys as k>
  ${k}
</#list>
```

output:

```
item
```

but the expected output is :

```
item
item
```

How to get the duplicate keys in freemarker?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. A Map only stores one element for each key.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. A dict contains only one value per key.